# Create an array in jquery from a php multidimensional array

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I have a php multidimensional array that I am sending to jquery but I need to automatically create the array.

All the examples show setting up a manual array like so:

```
var theme_name    = current_theme_meta.theme_name,
    theme_version = current_theme_meta.version,
    data0A        = theme_metadata[0].dataA,
    data0B        = theme_metadata[0].dataB,
    data1A        = theme_metadata[1].dataA,
    data1B        = theme_metadata[1].dataB;
```

current_theme_meta and theme_metadata are keys in php array I built and I push to jQuery via wp_localize_script() (a wordpress function.)

theme_name, version, dataA, and dataB are key values inside the array.

My array looks like this:

```
[current_theme_meta] => Array
    (
        [theme_name] => A Cool Theme
        [version] => 2.1.1
    )

[theme_meta] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [dataA] => foo
                [dataB] => bar
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [dataA] => this
                [dataB] => that
            )
    )
```

How do I create the array in jquery? I am confused between each and loop, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy way to do it would be to encode your PHP array as JSON using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), and then pass it to your JavaScript.

An example would be:

```
<?php
    //Create & populate your PHP array
    $my_php_array = array(
        'foo'  => 'bar',
        'test' => array(
                'abc' => '123'
            )
    );
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var my_javascript_object = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($my_php_array); ?>");
</script>
```

After that, you can access your JavaScript object as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(my_javascript_object.foo);
    alert(my_javascript_object.test.abc);
</script>
```

Comment: That does sound like the easiest way...so I basically do not need to setup the array on the jquery side as the key => value will just be passed and I can call the key/value pair. Thanks, I will play around with how to pass the array as json from inside wordpress.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. You'll do all your array building/manipulation in PHP, and pass the completed array as a JSON string, which is then parsed by JavaScript into an object.

Answer (score 1):

json_encode in your PHP, then parse the json in your jQuery:

```
$json = json_encode($your_array);
```

Then access it, and parse it in your Javascript:

```
var yourArray = JSON.parse('<?php echo $json ;?>');
```

JSON similar to XML is great for exchanging data between languages, as most languages have built in functions for dealing with it - as you can see in this example.